# FMX StringGrid low performance on phone XE5

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, stringgrid

I have performance issue in FM, I DON'T use binding because its epic slow I just filling the StringGrid from SQL manually and after build->deploy etc. And the scrolling in the StringGrid is slow not like in binding.
Is there any cheat to speed up this or something else
EDIT: Max 100 Rows so not a huge data

Comment: Are you filling the StringGrid during scrolling? - or do you fill all fields at once, so the scrolling is done with static data?

Comment: The second, after filling the SG scrolling is very slow

Comment: Did you ever try to upgrade your IDE to newer version?

Comment: Nope I didnt updated because its not a solution... :/